# Number of divisors $d$ of $n^2$ so that $d\nmid n$ and $d>n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, divisor-sum

I just wanted to share this nutshell with you guys, it is a little harder in this particular case of the problem:

> Find the number of divisors $d$ of $a^2=(2^{31}3^{17})^2$ so that $d>a$. What is the solution for the general case?

Comment: $d>n$ implies $d$ can't divide $n$.

Comment: The question is formatted like that because it gives you a hint.

Comment: Ah well. Fair enough :)

Comment: It actually doesn't really help solve the problem to know that $d\not\mid n$ - it is both redundant and a red herring.

Comment: It does. The number of values so that $d<n$ is intimately related to the number of values of $d$ so that $d$ does not divide $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General question**: Number of divisors of $n^2$ that are greater than $n$

Let $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ (and hence, $n^2=p_1^{2a_1}p_2^{2a_2}\dots p_k^{2a_k}$) where $p_i$'s are primes and $a_i$'s are positive integers. The number of divisors of $n$ is $(a_1+1)\cdots (a_k+1)$. If $n^2=a\cdot b$, then wlog $a\le n \le b$ (every divisor of $n^2$ smaller than $n$ has a counterpart which is greater than $n$). Omitting the divisor $n$, the number of divisors of $n^2$ which are greater than $n$ are $\frac{(2a_1+1)\cdots (2a_k+1)-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of divisors is (17+1)*(31+1)-1=575.
d/a^2 and d>a.
{1,2,2^2,...,2^31}*{1,3,3^2,...,3^17}={(1,1),(1,3),(1,3^2),...,(1,2),(1,2^2),...}
From (e,f) then e*f is one divisor of a.
d=e*f*a is devisor of a^2.